# Where is the forward button in Internet Explorer?

Tags: functionality, buttons, internet-explorer

I can't find a forward button in IE. It is very frustrating when I am filling some form on the page and accidentally touch the back button and the page with the filled form is gone. There is no way to get back to page with the form (which is the classic function of the forward button in browsers).

Any advice (other than "don't touch the back button" :) ) ?

Comment: which version of Windows Phone do you have?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A workaround is to make a JavaScript [bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) in your Favourites.

Name it `.Forward` (with a dot in front), so that it is always at the top of your Favourites list.

```
javascript:history.forward()
```

Comment: This is very nice! I would give you another +1 for the information that bookmarklets are working in IE. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

On my Mango, MS seems to have replaced "Forward" in IE with "Recent". The "Recent" option in the menu keeps a history of all the pages you've visited in chronological order. So if you start at page A, browse to page B, then back to A, you'll see B just under A in recent and can use that to go "forward".

Comment: @doug sorry for unaccepting your answer, but solution with bookmarklet is just awesome.

Comment: @jumbo no need to apologize!

Comment: +1. This is IMHO the more appropriate answer, merely because this question was about OOB functionality, and this one is it.

Answer (score 3):

Simply swipe to the left to browse forward, or right to browse back. ;)